# Error: Could not load template Opencart Version 2.2.0.0

Tags: opencart2.x, opencart-module

I am getting an error code. Although I have the permission to the desired directory, I am still getting the error. Please help.

> **Notice: Error: Could not load template**
>
> **`/home/domain/public_html/in/catalog/view/theme/default/template/default/template/payment/payu.tpl! in
>   /home/domain/public_html/in/vqmod/vqcache/vq2-system_library_template_basic.php
>   on line 26`**

Comment: Under what circumstances does this error present?

Comment: After Payment Method> i Choose a PayUMoney Checkout, then get the error. screen shot link is given below     http://prntscr.com/ad2dlo

Comment: Is `payu.tpl` present in `/catalog/view/theme/default/template/payment/` folder ? Check your controller file for the path to the template as `default/template` is being repeated!

Comment: are you using of any extension ?

Comment: show some code regarding loading template

Answer (score 2):

I solved this by removing **default/template/** in **catalog\controller\payment\payu.php**